# ffmpeg -- How do I overlay a PNG over another PNG?

Tags: ffmpeg, png, alpha-channel

I have PNG `A` with alpha layer, which I want to overlay on top of another PNG `B`. How do I do that with `ffmpeg`?

I tried `ffmpeg -i A.png -i B -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0" out.png`, but I only see `B`.

Here is the command output.

```
> frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A
> speed=0.0883x video:2169kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB
> global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown ffmpeg version
> N-83044-g2a293ec Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers   built
> with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)   configuration:
> --prefix=/data/local/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/data/local/ffmpeg_build/include
> --extra-ldflags=-L/data/local/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/data/local/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree   libavutil      55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100   libavcodec     57. 72.100 / 57. 72.100   libavformat    57. 62.100 / 57. 62.100   libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100   libavfilter     6. 68.100 / 
> 6. 68.100   libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101   libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100   libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100 Input #0, png_pipe, from '/data/output/067_90.png':
> Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
>     Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 2560x1440, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Output #0, image2, to
> '/data/output/067_90_down2.png':
> Metadata:
>     encoder         : Lavf57.62.100
>     Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>     Metadata:
>       encoder         : Lavc57.72.100 png Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> png (native)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A
> speed=0.163x video:134kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB
> global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Works for me. Show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Please see the upated question. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to overlay A on top of B, you need to switch either the file input order or the overlay ingest order.

```
ffmpeg -i B.png -i A.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2:-1[b];[0:v][b] overlay" out.png
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried, still to no avail. :-(

Comment: Can you add `-report` and run my command? Link to the report generated.

Comment: There you go -- http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=71172992522639780031. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You want 065_0 to be on top of 065?

Comment: That's right! :-)

Comment: Assuming the alpha layer isn't all black, use the edited cmd.

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot! Could you kindly also explain `[1]...[b]` and `overlay`? Can I in general combine many commands into one?

Comment: Your overlay image is twice the size of the base image, so I inserted a scale filter to downsize it. `[1]` is short for 'pick the best matching stream' (`[1:v]` is short for pick the best matching video stream - same thing in this case) and `[b]` is the label for the scale output which is then fed to the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

thia answer is not using *ffmpeg* yet... (i try to achieve the same but with a huge amount of images and oputput to a video file) but...

using the *convert* and *composite* command from *imagemagick* could help, the result is an animated gif, mpeg or either a single image.

this creates an animated gif with "overlay":

```
convert -delay 100 -loop 0 *.png test.gif
```

this will result in an mpeg file:

```
convert *.png test.mpeg
```

(anyway, for the mpeg file *convert* also runs ffmpeg :)

to just write an overlayed image file from multiple input files, you could use *composite* command from *imagemagick*:

```
composite -gravity center a.png b.png out.png
```

this overlays *b.png* (e.g. background) with *a.png* (e.g. foreground) preserving transparency.
the output is written to *out.png*

or use more input images, the last one is the output image:

```
composite -gravity center a.png b.png c.png out.png
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/

Answer (score 0):

Specify a codec *and* format that support alpha, for instance `-c:v png -pix_fmt rgba`.  To see which codecs you have, `ffmpeg -codecs`.  To see which formats you have, `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`.

Comment: Thanks, but I added the two options, but it's still not working.